# Beginner - Infinite Loop with Scanner Object

Tags: java, loops, io, java.util.scanner

In the following code, I get an infinite loop if an enter anything that causes an `InputMismatchException` in the `try` part below

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       double x;
       boolean b = true;
       while (b) {
           try {
               x = in.nextDouble(); //Enter 4a
               b = false;
           } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
               System.out.println("Wrong");
               // in.nextLine();
           }
       }
       in.close();
   }
```

If I uncomment the `in.nextLine();`, the code works fine. I am wondering why there is an infinite loop. I do not see why there would be an infinite loop because after the `catch` part is executed, I should be able to enter data when the `try` part is executed again. Why does this not happen?

Comment: Because if the conversion was unsuccessful, the Scanner does not advance past the input.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Would I be correct in saying that since the position value does not get updated, `in.nextLine()` "takes" the invalid token (from the `in.nextDouble();`) and because it takes the token, the position value changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Scanner javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()):

> Scans the next token of the input as a double. This method will throw
>   InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a
>   valid double value. If the translation is successful, the scanner
>   advances past the input that matched.

So as MFisherKDX commented, the scanner advances *only* if the input is a valid double. Hence, the token has to be skipped programmatically.

Comment: Not necessary to skip the whole line, just the current token. `in.next()` is enough. In most cases.

Comment: Right. Modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Scanner maintains a position variable.

```
// The index into the buffer currently held by the Scanner
private int position;
```

In case of the exception the position value doesn't get updated and the scanner keeps trying to read from the same position containing your invalid token.

```
in.nextLine()
```

The above line moves the position variable past the incorrect token and is ready to read fresh data in the buffer.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that since the position value does not get updated, `in.nextLine()` "takes" the invalid token (for the `in.nextDouble();`) and because it takes the token, the position value changes?

Comment: In this case yes, your understanding is right. However if your buffer contained `4a 4`, the position in buffer will be moved past both or as many tokens are there on the line and the buffer will move to reading from the next line.

Answer (score 0):

So what `in.nextLine();` does is consume the new line left over. In your case, when exception occurs, this is not performed and your code goes in infinite loop.

So either `in.nextDouble()` or `in.nextLine()` require to consume the line left over.

Comment: Not sure. But maybe because it's wrong or a typo. Reminds me of the definition of insanity: "doing the same thing over and over and expecting a different result." ;)  `in.nextDouble()` isn't going to fix an issue caused by a failing `in.nextDouble()`.

Comment: I didn't  downvote, but do you mean I could put ``in.nextDouble();` where `in.nextLine();` is an it will still work? I get an error if I do that.

Comment: @MFisherKDX no I mean if exception occurs then in.nextLine() is required, otherwise in.nextDouble() will work.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, just trying to give you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for infinite loop is pointer(can be said position) which Scanner keeps to access the element and after accessing the element, pointer is advanced.

But When any of Scanner Method (i.e. , `next()` , `nextDouble()` ),throws an exception, you are still at the same position/pointer at which Scanner tried to access the element and exception has been thrown.

As you are already catching the Exception in `catch` statement but the pointer is still there (at the same position) which will continuously throw an exception, to avoid this, you must advance the pointer using `.nextLine()`. which will move pointer to next line for accepting next Input.